# How do I grab the JSON data from a response from a client side GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, express

So this is my client side GET request to the server to grab some JSON data.

```
fetch("/" + "?foo=bar", {
               method: "GET",
               
           }).then(response => {
               console.log("JSON DATA:", response)
           })
```

This is how my GET request end point is written (lower half is the relevant part)

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
        mysql.pool.query("SELECT * FROM workouts", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
                let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))
                for (let entry of parsedData) {
                    // changing 1 and 0 to represent lbs or kg
                    if (entry.lbs == 1) {entry.lbs = "lbs"}
                    else {entry.lbs = "kg"}
                    
                    //formatting the date
                    let formattedDate = new Date(entry.date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'});
                    entry.date = formattedDate
                }
              let data = {
                    entry: parsedData
              }
              console.log("REQ.QUERY", req.query)
              if (req.query.foo) {
                  //send JSON data back to client
                  console.log(parsedData)
                  res.json({test:"hello"})
              } else {
                res.render("home", data)
              }
              
            }
          })
})
```

As you can see I am doing res.json({test:"hello"}) as the response. That means I when I console.log(response) on the client side, it should come up with {test:"hello"} right? But instead I get the following response. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is a `Response`, which does not directly have the response. You should call [`.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) on it:

```js
fetch("/?foo=bar")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res); // already json parsed object
    });
```

If you don't want to parse as JSON or have a non-json response, use `.text()` instead.

[Read more about fetch here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: super helpful, thank you!! Also, just for my knowledge, why doesn't res.json() need the curly brackets around it like below.

fetch("/?foo=bar")
    .then(res => {res.json()})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res); // already json parsed object
    });

Comment: For arrow functions, when there are no curly braces, it means to return the expression. In this case, `res.json()` is returned in order to utilize promise chaining.